# get one element from arraylist xml using xstream

Tags: java, xml, arraylist, xstream

hello guys i have xml file like this :

```
<data>
    <pattern>^[sS].*</pattern>
    <destination>C:\\Server\\s\\</destination>
</data>

<data>
    <pattern>^[dD].*</pattern>
    <destination>C:\\Server\\d\\</destination>
</data>
```

i make xml to object like this :

```
    XStream xstream = new XStream(new StaxDriver());
        // Datas datas = new Datas();
        File xmlx = new File("E:\\FileConfig.xml");

        xstream.alias("datas", Datas.class);
        xstream.alias("data", DataRegex.class);

        xstream.processAnnotations(DataRegex.class);
        xstream.processAnnotations(Datas.class);

        Datas dataz = (Datas) xstream.fromXML(xmlx);
```

i have class datas and DataRegex :

```
@XStreamAlias("data")
public class DataRegex {
    public String getPattern() {
        return pattern;
    }

    public void setName(String pattern) {
        this.pattern = pattern;
    }

    public String getDes() {
        return destination;
    }

    public void setDes(String destination) {
        this.destination = destination;
    }

    @XStreamAlias("destination")
    private String destination;
    @XStreamAlias("pattern")
    private String pattern;
}
```

next, i want to get one element from the array element like 'pattern' value to compare with any data in if-else condition. anybody can help me ?